# Stop React Slick right draggable after going to last slide

Tags: reactjs, slick.js, react-slick

```
https://github.com/akiran/react-slick
```

I'm facing problem related to padding. After the last slide, we are able to see space if you drag.

```
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/opdadq 
http://jsfiddle.net/kirana/wna3a6q5
```

with the settings: slidesToShow: 2, slidesToScroll: 1

The user should scroll only one slide at a time.

[image]

Comment: code pen example is reloading multiple times. Please post a valid codepen example

Comment: Added one more jsfiddle link. Specify props with given settings. Thank you.